# How to apply css to all pages in custom module

Tags: 7, theming

I have created one custom module in drupal-7. I want to apply same css to all pages belonging to that module.

I am able to apply css to one page by using **drupal_add_css()** but not able to do for all pages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In module's info file, add following line:

```
stylesheets[all][] = folder/module.css
```

Substitute `folder` with a name of subfolder within your module you keep your CSS files in (or remove it). Repeat for all CSS files you need.

More about info files [in the manual on Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/542202).

Answer (score 0):

1- Place style.css in my_module folder

2-
in my_modulefolder/my_module.module

```
function my_module_preprocess(&$vars, $hook) {    
  if($hook == 'page')    
   drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') .'/style.css');
}
```